# HTTP request host header using netcat (nc)

Tags: command-line, security, webserver, https, netcat

How to use netcat (nc) to set host header in a HTTP request?

Comment: Please could you put some details in? Your os, hardware, what you’ve tried, what wire errors you’re getting. Help us to help you! Thanks.

Comment: I'm doing an open-source training on cybersecurity provided by ASU. As a newbie in cybersecurity I was stuck at challenges. The OS is Ubuntu Linux and connected to their workspace through ssh-key remotely as instructed by them. But later I have figured out the answer, it was already hidden in their lectures and walkthroughs. Thank you Will!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:
nc localhost 80
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: de5c31dc1bdfeb2c165d1d1a91cf5588
Some-other-head: wow
Content-length: 100